# what does order 1,2 do

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Imagine  we have following table

```
create table t
  (item number,
   bin number,
   primary key (bin , item) );
```

I have used  insert into  command to insert several values into table `t`, now i am interested  in what does  this code

```
select * from t
  order by 1,2;
```

As far as i know it selects everything from table `t` and sorts it, because order means to sort selected query  using condition listed in order command, but `order 1,2` i could not understand  what does it means, could  you help me ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sorts the result by the first and second column, so in your case it's identical to

```
select *
from t
order by item, bin;
```

Answer (score 6):

It will order the results by the first column, and then, if there are some rows with the same value in the first column it will order them by the second column.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from t
  order by item, bin; // just different written but result is same.
```

`Result` will be sorted by first and second column.

Difference is in readability of code so if someone don't know information about table, your `select` says nothing him. Person only knows that result will be sorted by 1. and 2. column, nothing more.

Comment: To add to this: sometimes it can be useful like when you have a computation in a result column. Then rather than having to add the computation into the sort (as well as the select), you can just specify the position of the computed column.

Comment: @SeanW - You can also order by column alias for that case. The only time I ever use order by column ordinal is in adhoc throw away queries.

Comment: @MartinSmith good point. I also use it when I have the same column name twice in a result, eg: "SELECT dateinserted, * FROM table ORDER BY 1". Usually dateinserted is the last column in a long list and I'm too lazy to scroll right. (Only for debugging something in SSMS)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as regular *ORDER BY* clause but kind of assigns numeric aliases to the column names.
In your case, 1 = 'item number' and 2 = 'bin number'.

Same as:

```
SELECT * FROM t
ORDER BY item number, bin number;
```